# Script to verify 15 second timestamp difference

Tags: bash, timestamp

With a bash script, I am trying to verify that there is 15 seconds between file modifications.  If I have:

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 root      root           2739 Jun 05 00:43 1370392620.log
-rw-rw-r--  1 root      root           2739 Jun 05 00:37 1370392623.log
-rw-rw-r--  1 root      root           2739 Jun 05 00:37 1370392626.log
-rw-rw-r--  1 root      root           2739 Jun 05 00:37 1370392630.log
```

I need to be able to get the seconds difference between these timestamps, and verify that they are 15 seconds apart.

Comment: If you have GNU `ls`, it has a `--full-time` option that includes the seconds. Or check if your system has the `stat` command, which can return the modification time as seconds since the epoch.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: If you have `stat`, it should be easy to pipe the output of this to an `awk` script that checks the time differences.

Comment: I am running QNX.  This does not support a --full-time option or stat. This is the constant problem I am running into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
last=0
ls -rt *.log |
while read fname 
do
  epoch_seconds=$(date -r $fname +%s)
  if [ $last -gt 0 ]; then
    printf "%20s   diff: %10d   %13d\n" "$fname"  $(( $epoch_seconds - $last )) $epoch_seconds
    [  $(( $epoch_seconds - $last )) -ne 15 ]  && echo "file mtime difference error"
    last=$epoch_seconds     
  else
    printf "%20s   start %10d   %13d\n" "$fname" 0  $epoch_seconds
    last=$epoch_seconds
  fi

done
```

The `date -f filename` command (GNU) returns the mtime (last time written, i.e. closed time), formatted as `+%s` gives epoch seconds.  Subtract first file mtime from next file, `ls -rt` sorts file by reverse mtime -i.e., oldest first, newest last.

Comment: Jim, this is a great start. I am using (QNX) and switched the date -r to date -t to get the epoch times. I am now working with an error:    [: 0: unexpected operator/operand

Comment: It is complaining about the position of the [, assuming your version bash is remotely POSIX compliant. [ and ] are keywords, they have to have spaces on both sides of them like any other keyword.  Failing that try an if ; then fi construct for the now-single line that checks time differences.